# Add product category name on order page in admin

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to add product category name to the admin order page in Woocommerce?

Right now it only display the product name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this??

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta','woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta',10,3);

function woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta($item_id, $item, $product){
   echo '<p>'.get_the_term_list($product->id, 'product_cat').'</p>';
}
```

this code will display category below the product name.

Comment: BTW: $product->id should be $item['product_id']